# Include jquery in Magento extension, but only on extension page

Tags: magento

My Magento extension needs jQuery for its admin panel page.  I found a tutorial online on how to include jQuery in my extension.

Here's how I'm including it.

~app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/myextension.xml

```
<default>
  <action method="addItem">
   <type>skin_js</type>
   <name>myextension/js/jquery.js</name>
   <params/>
  </action>
</default>
```

This works, but my problem is that this including jquery.js in ALL admin pages.  This is causing issues with other extensions.  How can I make it so that jQuery will only be included when I go to my extensions admin page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change

`<default></default>`

to

`<adminhtml_url_key_for_your_extension><adminhtml_url_key_for_your_extension/>`

when you use default for your target it hits all pages

Comment: this is the right way. adminhtml_url_key_for_your_extension means like if your controller actions is like myextension_adminhtml_mycontroller_myaction then use this way <myextension_adminhtml_mycontroller_myaction>....</myextension_adminhtml_mycontroller_myaction>

Comment: yeah it should be the same as what generates the page, www.site.com/dashboard/index would be <adminhtml_dashboard_index></adminhtml_dashboard_index>